# Can I upgrade Ubuntu to 9.10 from 8.10, without using an ISO image?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

Is there a way to upgrade to Ubuntu 9.10 *without* having to download and use an ISO image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's really non-geek if you follow the instructions to the letter. Fire up Terminal, and type the following line :

> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

There's a way with Synaptics, but trust me, this is waaaay easier.

**EDIT : Missed out that OP wanted to upgrade to 9.10, which hasn't been released yet.**

Do the above pre-edit answer first to upgrade to 9.04 (just to be safe). Then :

Type in Terminal

> update-manager -d

Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '9.10' is available. Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: But will this get me 9.10, not 9.04

Comment: Oh sorry! Forgot you were upgrading to yet-to-be released Karmic Koala. Okay editing answer.

Comment: In 8.10, not upgraded, it still says upgrade to 9.04

Comment: upgrade to 9.04 first, then upgrade to 9.10. don't skip versions - things might break.

Comment: It takes hours to upgrade though

Comment: Right. :X For fastest upgrade, just burn the disc, do a clean install. Oh, and spend X hours copying your data back and getting everything customized to your liking again.

Comment: ONLY to have to upgrade again when Karmic Koala hits the release version. You do the maths.

Answer (score 4):

First, Use the [Ubuntu Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JauntyUpgrades) to upgrade to 9.04, since they [advise not skipping versions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes#General%20Upgrade%20Information).

Then you can use [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KarmicKoala/TechnicalOverview#Upgrading%20from%20Ubuntu%209.04) to get you up to the 9.10 pre-release.

Comment: From 8.10, please

Comment: @Pajarito: The Ubuntu guide has instructions for upgrading from 8.10 to 9.04. That should have everything you need to get to 9.10

Answer (score 0):

gd: update manager turning gray

I had the same issue upgrading to 9.10. Therefore, I first run all upgrades for my existing ubuntu version. I had to go through a couple of update cycles. This included an upgrade of the download manager.
After this, I could upgrade to 9.10 without problems.